# ID based queuing

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I want to be able to run tasks in parallel across different machines *except* when they match by some string identifier, in which case I want them to queue in single file (i.e. one by one). The identifiers are not known in advance, but they will be known at the time of any one particular task creation.

What would be the simplest way of getting this to work, including any libraries that might help in simplifying it?